# Latex doesn't create new page when using section?

Tags: sectioning, document-classes, article

I'm trying to create my document with lots of section. However, after the document is compiled by pdfLaTeX, the document showed like this:
[image: The document goes out of boundary of paper]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{aaa}  % * a lots of time
\end{document}
```

How to make sure the sections doesn't goes out of bond and create new page automatically?

Comment: Place some text between the section commands.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Yes, that's the expected behaviour. LaTeX prevents page-breaking after all section titles. It would be awkward to have a section title at the bottom of the page and the text starting on the next page, thus this is the way it is. In normal documents this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: When you are testing with code like this, always remember to add text to each section.